# FloatingActionButton doesn't hide

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I am trying to hide my FloatingActionButton `fabLocation` programmatically with :

```
fabLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

but it does not work.

If I add `android:visibility="gone"` in my XML layout, `fabLocation` is hidden when I run my activity but it reappears when I scroll.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorOverlay"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_couverture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_navigation_drawer_header"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="16dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <View
                    android:background="@drawable/separator_orange_gradient"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_history"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.RobotoLight" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/fab_location"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_location_24dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrange"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is due to the `app:layout_anchor` attribute. You must get rid of the anchor before changing visibility:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: How do we do this if we use fab.hide() instead of setVisibility(View.GONE)? Because right now your example will show the fab animate (getting smaller) in the top left of the screen for a split second before it dissapears, which is unwanted behavior, ideally you would want it to hide on the spot.

Comment: @Linxy have the same issue

Comment: For others like me. having the same issue with the animation. The solution is to set the fab.width and fab.height to zero as mentioned in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732932/floatingactionbutton-visible-for-sometime-even-if-visibility-is-set-to-gone

Comment: @Linxy: if you still need this, see my answer below. Even setting to width and height 0 didn't help me, I ended up removing and adding the FAB from the parent layout completely.

Comment: my FAB is inside the relative layout without app:layout_anchor and also tried setVisiblity programmatically and through XML. Any solution for this?

Comment: It does not work for me so i just set "x" of fab. fab.x = -500f; and fab.x = oldPos; for bring it back

Answer (score 16):

FloatingActionButtons anchored to AppBarLayouts have a special relationship where their visibility is controlled by the scroll position of the AppBarLayout.

You can turn this off via the `behavior_autoHide` attribute:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_anchor="..."
    app:behavior_autoHide="false"/>
```

You can also do this programmatically if you wish:

**EDIT:**

<s>fab.getBehavior()</s> was not correct, use `getBehavior()` from its `LayoutParams`

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
FloatingActionButton.Behavior behavior = (FloatingActionButton.Behavior) lp.getBehavior();
if (behavior != null) {
    behavior.setAutoHideEnabled(false);
} else {
    behavior = new FloatingActionButton.Behavior();
    behavior.setAutoHideEnabled(false);
    lp.setBehavior(behavior);
}
```

Comment: fab.getBehavior() method not found?

Comment: It works. get behavior from CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Using `behavior_autoHide` is not enough. By default it's created with default constructor. To make this attribute works you must specify `layout_behavior` explicit to `com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton$Behavior`

Answer (score 15):

The most simplistic way to hide and show a floating action button would be to call this in your activity. This will also properly animate your FAB automatically.

Hide:

```
nameOfYourFAB.Hide();
```

Show:

```
nameOfYourFAB.Show();
```

Comment: this does not work in all cases e.g FAB in  CoordinatorLayout is involved

Answer (score 14):

I wasn't completely happy with any of the solutions posted. Some only worked part of the time, while others only worked for `fab.setVisibility()`. While I know this is technically what the original question asked, a few responses expressed interest in using `fab.hide()`, and messing with the layout parameters doesn't exactly get to the root of the issue.

As pointed out by @ChrisBanes, the `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` being tied to the `AppBarLayout` is what causes the issue. So, as with his answer, you have to `setAutoHideEnabled(false)` to disable that functionality. But this solution doesn't help if you actually want the `FloatingActionButton` to hide automatically *and* when you call `hide()` manually.

So in order to do this; I simply disable the auto-hide functionality before I manually hide the `Button`, then re-enable the functionality after I manually show the `Button`:

```
private void hideFloatingActionButton(FloatingActionButton fab) {
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =
            (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
    FloatingActionButton.Behavior behavior =
            (FloatingActionButton.Behavior) params.getBehavior();

    if (behavior != null) {
        behavior.setAutoHideEnabled(false);
    }

    fab.hide();
}

private void showFloatingActionButton(FloatingActionButton fab) {
    fab.show();
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params =
            (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
    FloatingActionButton.Behavior behavior =
            (FloatingActionButton.Behavior) params.getBehavior();

    if (behavior != null) {
        behavior.setAutoHideEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
FloatingActionButton layers = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.layers);
layers.hide();
```

It works for me, `setVisibility` doesn't work for `FloatingActionButton` as it belongs to another `viewGroup` that doesn't have `setVisibility` method.

Comment: It works for me, setVisibility does't work for FloatingActionButton as it belongs to another viewGroup that does't have setVisibility method.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to show hidden FAB

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    ...

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    ...

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and

```
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END;
    p.setAnchorId(R.id.appbar);
    p.setMargins(...);
    fab.setLayoutParams(p);
    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks ! useful to get button back.

Answer (score 3):

After some answers around, I founded the solution for my problem(also when the fab is hidden it can handle action!).

First of all I suggest you to replace `.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` with the methods `.show()` and `.hide()`. These last handle also `actionMode`.

The second problem for me was the action also handled when the fab was hidden, for resolve this I made it:

```
final CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)floatingActionButton.getLayoutParams();
    if (show){
        p.setAnchorId(R.id.appBarLayout);
        p.width = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        p.height = CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        floatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(p);
        floatingActionButton.show();
    }else{
        p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
        p.width = 0;
        p.height = 0;
        floatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(p);
        floatingActionButton.hide();
    }
```

Comment: Oh, Android, why so complex? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The real solution for your problem is to subclass default `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` to call `setAutoHide(false)` in their constructors, so you can control it yourself.

*Note that I talk about bottom sheets below, but it is exactly the same problem for all anchored Floating Action Buttons, and it does respond to the question and should solve the problem as expected.*

Alternatively, you can override the `boolean onDependentViewChanged(…)` method from your custom Behavior, copy the `isBottomSheet(…)` static method present in the `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` class, and only call & return the value of the super method if it's not a bottom sheet.

You can further customize the default behavior this way, or by extending the vanilla `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior` class directly, and you can cherry pick code to copy paste from the `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` class if needed.

Here's the code I used to control back the FAB visibility:

```
/**
 * Allows controlling the FAB visibility manually.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class FabManualHideBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public FabManualHideBehavior() {
        super();
        setAutoHideEnabled(false);
    }

    public FabManualHideBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setAutoHideEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And I applied it to my FAB in xml this way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    ...>
    ...
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        ...
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end"
        app:layout_behavior="your.package.name.ui.behavior.FabManualHideBehavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is simple solution

```
private var fabAnchorId: Int = View.NO_ID
private val fabParams: CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        get() = (fab.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)

fun showFab() {
    fabParams.anchorId = fabAnchorId
    fabParams.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY
    fab.show()
}

fun hideFab() {
    fabParams.anchorId = View.NO_ID
    fabParams.gravity = Gravity.END.or(Gravity.BOTTOM)
    fab.hide()
}
```

before show/hide we have to change anchor and gravity

Answer (score 0):

None of these other solutions helped me 100%.  I needed repeated, animated show and hide (like `FAB.show()` and `hide()`) all while anchored to the app bar when visible.

I ended up creating the FAB new every time I showed it, manually inserting and anchoring it, and animating it based on the support library implementation.  It's gross, but it works perfectly.

```
private void hidePlayButton(final FloatingActionButton fab) {
    // Cancel any animation from the default behavior
    fab.animate().cancel();
    fab.animate()
               .scaleX(0f)
               .scaleY(0f)
               .alpha(0f)
               .setDuration(200)
               .setInterpolator(new FastOutLinearInInterpolator())
               .setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                   @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

                   @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                      coordinatorLayout.removeView(fab);
                   }

                   @Override public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

                   @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
               });
}

private void showPlayButton() {
    int fabSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_size);
    int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fab_margin);
    final FloatingActionButton fab = new FloatingActionButton(getActivity());
    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.tint)));
    fab.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.play));
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(fabSize, fabSize);
    p.rightMargin = p.leftMargin = p.bottomMargin = p.topMargin = margin;
    p.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END;
    p.setAnchorId(R.id.appbar);
    fab.setLayoutParams(p);
    // Start from 1 pixel
    fab.setAlpha(0f);
    fab.setScaleX(0f);
    fab.setScaleY(0f);
    binding.coordinatorLayout.addView(fab);
    fab.animate()
       .alpha(1f)
       .scaleX(1f)
       .scaleY(1f)
       .setDuration(200)
       .setInterpolator(new FastOutLinearInInterpolator());

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            hidePlayButton(fab);
            // do action
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code :

```
   public static void setVisibilityFab(FloatingActionButton fab, int visibility)
  {

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
        p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
        fab.setLayoutParams(p);
        if(visibility==View.GONE || visibility==View.INVISIBLE)
            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        else
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you answer is about how to make it work for `gone` visibility but if you use `invisible` instead you will have no worries about that and is less code.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the show()/hide() shortcoming by placing the FAB in or out of the screen using layout margins. example:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p =
   new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(
      CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

p.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
int fabMargin = (int)res.getDimension(R.dimen.fab_margin);

if( enabled ) {
   p.setMargins(fabMargin,0,0,fabMargin);
}
else {
   p.setMargins(-200,0,0,fabMargin);
}
mFab.setLayoutParams(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

I you use this code:

```
boolean mFabShouldBeShown;
FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener fabListener = new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShown(FloatingActionButton fab) {
            super.onShown(fab);
            if(!mFabShouldBeShown){
                fab.hide();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
            super.onHidden(fab);
            if(mFabShouldBeShown){
                fab.show();
            }
        }
};

public void methodWhereFabIsHidden() {
    mFabShouldBeShown = false;
    mFloatingActionButton.hide(fabListener);
}

public void methodWhereFabIsShown() {
    mFabShouldBeShown = true;
    mFloatingActionButton.show(fabListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the fab, you can try this:
fab.hide();

else try
fab.show();

enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the floating button

```java
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
fab.hide;
```

and to re-show

```java
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setAnchorId(View.NO_ID);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
fab.show;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using this:

```
fab.setEnabled(false);
fab.setClickable(false);
fab.setAlpha(0.0f);
```

This is similar behavior as `View.Gone`