# Hide floating action button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, nestedscrollview

Update: I have solved this problem just by listen to the scroll change event of the NestedScrollView and do the appropriate handling there.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/floating-action-buttons#animating-the-floating-action-button) to animate showing and hiding of my `FloatingActionButton`. But it doesn't really work for my layout. My layout is like this picture:

[image]

It has a NestedScrollView and a number of RecyclerView inside. When I scroll by touching the area of NestedScrollView, the `FloatingActionButton` is animated as expected. But when I scroll by touching the area of one of the `RecyclerViews`, the `FloatingActionButton` don't animate at all. When I try debug my code, I realize that the `onNestedScroll` method doesn't gets called when I scroll by touching on the area of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FloatingActionButton doesn't hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269958/floatingactionbutton-doesnt-hide)

Answer (score -1):

Comment out or delete this code block from your xml layout

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```