# Any way to hide FAB(floating action button) via xml?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Is there any way to hide/disable Floating action button in Android via xml file without editing Java file? Just want to hide a share button in an app and I tried editing related xml file. Tried to set invisible, gone etc but none of these works. Button is still there. At least to reduce the size of button to almost invisible? I think we cant change `fab:fab_size="normal"` to other values. So that too didn't work. So is there any way??

Comment: Did you try visibility=gone ?

Comment: Can you show your XML where you used invisible attribute.

Comment: Similar question already answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269958/floatingactionbutton-doesnt-hide

Comment: yes. already tried visibility=gone, visibility=invisible but it's not working

Comment: Show your XML code

Comment: So this means, we can't hide it via xml only if app:layout_anchor attribute is there. Right? no other way to hide via xml?

Comment: what if you remove `app:layout_anchor` attribute ?

Comment: <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton android:id="@id/fab_sharing" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10.0dip" android:src="@drawable/ic_sharing_white_24dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" fab:fab_showShadow="true" fab:fab_shadowColor="#33000000" fab:fab_size="normal" fab:menu_colorNormal="#ffffb805" fab:menu_colorPressed="#fff2ab00" fab:menu_colorRipple="#ffd99200" />

Comment: No. deleting will not work. I tried but another activity important activity will not work if i delete it.

Comment: @shree krishana: I didn't tried that yet. i was asking, is there an way to do this without touching java. only via xml

Comment: Thanks everybody. i was aware of the app:layout_anchor issue before i posted the question, but my question was about hiding it via xml without touching java code. I think it's not possible. Anyway I'm keeping this question open. Let's see if anybody have some tricks to do this via xml only. Thanks a lot for replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Discussed](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175331) already on this issue,
Main reason is

> If you set a set a `FloatingActionButton` to be anchored, you *lose control* of the visibility.

So you have to remove `layout_anchor` attribute from `FloatingActionButton` first.

You have to use java somewhere at the point. Cant do it with only with `XML` The trick given is

> To wrap your FAB in a coordinator layout that is not the root of your entire layout, but as a sort of overlay to everything. From there you can manage the visibility of the coordinator layout initially so it's invisible, then make it visible when you call `fab.show()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
                android:id="@+id/menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
                fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
                fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/lightgrey"
                fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/transparant"
                fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
                fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/my_hide_animation"
                fab:menu_fab_label=""
                fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/my_show_animation"
                fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
                fab:menu_icon="@drawable/plus"
                fab:menu_openDirection="up"
                fab:menu_showShadow="false"
                android:visibility="gone">
```