# Prevent FloatingActionButton from disappearing on a CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a details fragment which shows information about a selected item. The image is embedded in a `CoordinatorLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The behavior works as expected: As the image is scrolled down, the `FloatingActionButton` scrolls up with the end of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Then as it gets fully collapsed the `FloatingActionButton` disappears. What I want to happen is that this button never disappears. It's fine that it's anchored to the toolbar, but I have been unable to find out how to keep it visible after looking in the docs and on this site. Any tips would be appreciated!

Here is a simplified version of my layout:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:title="@{movie.title}"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_details_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/browse_image_content_description"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:largeSize="@{true}"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:posterPath="@{movie.posterPath}" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.heiligbasil.movietvdelight.view.DetailsFragment">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_details_text_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@{movie.title}"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="10dp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_save" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to happen is that this button never disappears

It's actually because of `app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"` where your `FloatingActionButton` has special relation and controls by `AppBarLayout` while scrolling.

To disable that, set: [`app:behavior_autoHide="false"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.BaseBehavior#attr_FloatingActionButton_Behavior_Layout_behavior_autoHide) to your `FloatingActionButton`.

---

Also, you can do this programmatically using [`setAutoHideEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/FloatingActionButton.BaseBehavior#setAutoHideEnabled(boolean)). This is exactly what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43077760/4409113

Comment: The XML attribute didn't have any effect on the behavior, oddly however the programmatic solution worked! `val layoutParams = binding.fab.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
        var fabBehavior = layoutParams.behavior as? FloatingActionButton.Behavior
        fabBehavior?.let {
            it.isAutoHideEnabled = false
        } ?: run {
            fabBehavior = FloatingActionButton.Behavior()
            fabBehavior?.isAutoHideEnabled = false
            layoutParams.behavior = fabBehavior
        }`